# Make phonecall through watchkit application

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit

I am trying to show the User different Phone Numbers on Apple Watch and he clicks on one than phone call alert should appear. I'll do it like this but the Alert is just dismissed without call action:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
WKExtension *myExt = [WKExtension sharedExtension];
for (NSString *phone in arr) {
    NSString *tel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone];
    WKAlertAction *act = [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:tel style:WKAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(void){
        [myExt openSystemURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phone1]];
    }];
    [tempArray addObject:act];
}

NSString *titleMessage = @"Call";
NSString *textMessage = @"Please select the number you want to call.";
NSString *cancel = @"Cancel";

WKAlertAction *act = [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:cancel style:WKAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(void){

}];
[tempArray addObject:act];

[Self presentAlertControllerWithTitle: titleMessage message: textMessage preferredStyle: WKAlertControllerStyleAlert actions: temporary];
```

Buttons are shown as expected and the Handler is also called with the correct Phone Number. But it does not openSystemURL. Does somebody know why and how to fix? Thanks!